# PostgreSQL - Select Clause on WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to list all tables and it's sizes in a PGSQL server. I tryed to do the following:

```
select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = (SELECT datname FROM pg_database order by datname);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery
> used as an expression

What Am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Marcio

Comment: The error message says it all, you are trying to compare a single table_schema with several datname values. Try `where table_schema IN (SELECT ...` instead.

Comment: A database is not the same as a schema, so comparing `table_schema` with `datname` makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: Doing like this it will work, but I need to see all the tables in all the schemas: create table public.tabelas as
 select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))from information_schema.tables
 where table_schema = 'public'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT  table_catalog AS database
    ,   table_schema AS schemaname
    ,   table_name
    ,   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name))) as table_size
    ,   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name))) as total_size
FROM    information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```